# shortcut server side code blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net page and I need to add an optional parameter to href of hyperlink. Parameter value is in codebehind.

Here is the hyperlink:

```
<a href='FileView.aspx?fid=<%#Eval("FileOrFolderID") %>&uid=<%=UserID %> <%=(ProfileType.HasValue && ProfileId.HasValue?"&profiletype=" + (int)ProfileType.Value + "&profileid=" + ProfileId.Value:"") %>'
                                        <%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFolder")) ? "style='display:none;'" : "style='display:block;'" %>
                                        id="aDownLoad">
                                        <%# Eval("Name").ToString().HE()%></a>
```

I want to add this:

```
<%=(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFolder")) ? "" :  "&id=" + CurrentID) %>
```

so that it looks like this:

```
<a href='FileView.aspx?fid=<%#Eval("FileOrFolderID") %>&uid=<%=UserID %> <%=(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFolder")) ? "" :  "&id=" + CurrentID) %> <%=(ProfileType.HasValue && ProfileId.HasValue?"&profiletype=" + (int)ProfileType.Value + "&profileid=" + ProfileId.Value:"") %>'
                                        <%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFolder")) ? "style='display:none;'" : "style='display:block;'" %>
                                        id="aDownLoad">
                                        <%# Eval("Name").ToString().HE()%></a>
```

But is gives this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Please suggest solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eval and Bind can only be used if your control is being bound to a data source, which does not appear to be the case.
Use a server control:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="link" />
```

And set it's NavigationUrl property on code behind.